# How to remove part of filename in windows command prompt?

Tags: filenames

I have **Intro.ape.wav**, and I want to rename it into **Intro.wav**

I've tried ren *.ape.wav *.wav , w/o success.

Moreover I ran through many pages , also with echo %-ni, etc, but got no success either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Another view how to solve this question - I found this on my old hdd, where I operated many .dat files:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*.ape) do (set name=%%~ni
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Monkey's Audio\MAC.exe" "!name!.ape" "!name!.wav" -d
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you need a loop.  In bourne shell,

```
for i in *.ape.wav; do
  name=`echo $i | rev | cut -d. -f 3- | rev`
  mv $i $name.wav
done
```

Now... bourne shell is available on Windows 10 now... or you could write a loop in Microsoft's shell.

NB: This requires the command 'rev' ... which linux doesn't provide.  You could also do this with sed or, depending on whether your filenames contain other periods, just cut alone.  rev, however, just reverses the characters in the input.

Comment: Thanks zBeeble, but bash is not what I want to use in my windows7, sorry:)
I just need to remove ".ape" from filename, that is it..

Answer (score 1):

This is clumsy but will work as long as there's no files named `*.ape` in your directory.

```
ren *.ape.wav *.
ren *.ape *.wav
```

Comment: Thanks, this one is nice method :)